# Jenkins hide secrets in logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am seeing the following issues
While secrets/passwords are redacted in jenkins console log, redirecting output to a file prints teh secrets / passwords in plain text even with mask passwords plugin enabled

Steps to reproduce:
Create new freestyle job and do teh following steps

1. Select 'Inject passwords to the build as environment variables'
2. Select 'Global passwords'
3. Select 'Mask password parameters';
4. Add BuildStep 'Execute Shell';
   In the shell enter

```
env 2>&1 | tee "log.log"
```

5. Save the config
6. Build
7. Workspace
8. List item

open log.log and you will see the passwords printed in plain text

Is there any way to hide passwords / secrets from redirected output?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Once you redirect output to a file it's no longer managed by Jenkins and you have provide your own secret obfuscation.